# Which is better ? pagination or manual resultset slicing in django python?

Tags: python, django, pagination, slice

I am having a resultset and I want to implement kind of pagination on it. I know that django is having Paginator, but as an alternate way I can also have my own implementation i.e. slice the resultset for pagination support. So I think I can have two different approaches mentioned below.

Using Paginator:

```
paginator = Paginator(messages, 10)
messages = paginator.page(2)
```

or slicing...

```
messages = messages[start:start+10]
```

Among these two ways which one would be more efficient in terms of performance. I think using django pagination would be better idea, but before using it I just want to know that which way would be more better.

I can try both of these approach myself, but actually I just want to know in advance before starting implementation of it which help me to save time.

Any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paginator does slicing under the cover, but has some other handy functionality implemented. So if you do not wanna invent the wheel, use Paginator.

Comment: If pagination is also doing slicing internally and if I won't need much other handy functionality then would manual slicing more better ? I am asking it because I am checking on performance.

Comment: I bet you'll end up implementing all thos tiny powerups, such as `has_other_pages`, `start_index` etc. And most often all the bottlenecks lies in db, i doubt you'll see difference in performance.